# Convert 1D list into dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list with categories followed by some elements. Given that I know all the category names, is there a way to turn this into a dictionary of lists, i.e. convert:

```
l1 = ['cat1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat2', 1, 2, 3, 'cat3', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

into:

```
l1_dic = {'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Edit: It is possible that the categories do NOT have a common string e.g. 'cat1' could be replaced by 'Name' while 'cat2' could be 'Address'.

Like I said, in my original post, we do know the category names i.e. we do potentially have a list l2 such that:

```
l2 = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
```

Once again, the category names need not necessarily have a common string.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it as general as possible. So the elements could be of any type. My instinct was to use `index()` to find where the categories are and then extract lists in between. It would work except that the last category would have to be checked separately and I didn't think it was neat enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know the categories, a simple loop with tracking of the last key should work:

```
categories = {'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'}

out = {}
key = None
for item in l1:
    if item in categories:
        out[item] = []
        key = item
    else:
        out[key].append(item)
```

output:

```
{'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'cat2': [1, 2, 3],
 'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: @RWalser I might possible to have a one liner but it probably won't be elegant due to the nesting with the list. The classical loop is probably the most explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
d = {}
keys = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
for i in l1:
    if i in keys:
        key = i
        d.setdefault(i, [])
    else:
        d[key].append(i)

# Output 
{'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

You can iterate through the `l1` and assign a value to the dictionary that a specific keyword exists in `keys`.

Edit:

There has to be some condition to distinguish between key and value you can replace the corresponding condition with this `if 'cat' in str(i)`
For ex:

```
values = {'address_1', 'location_1', 'name_1'}
...
if i in values:
..
```

Comment: OP specified: "Once again, the category names need not necessarily have a common string." This solution does not respect this constraint.

Comment: @rahuk-k-p Yes, that works. You forgot to update your output.  I get {'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}.

Comment: Compared with the accepted answer this answer has the benefit of not overwriting previous values if the keyword appears more than once. The extra values will be added then due to the use of setdefault.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a functional approach to this using `functools.reduce`.

```
from functools import reduce

categories = {'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'}

reduce(lambda acc, x: (x, {x: [], **acc[1]}) if x in categories else \
                      (k:=acc[0], {**(d:=acc[1]), k: d[k] + [x]}), 
       l1, (None, dict()))[1]
# {'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

We need a tuple to track two pieces of information as we iterate: The last "key" and a dictionary storing the parsed data so far. If the current item *is a key* we update the current key info in the tuple dictionary with the new key, and we add an empty list to the dictionary using the new key.

If the current else otherwise is not a key, we obviously don't need to change the first element in the tuple, but we do update the dictionary with the updated list for that key.

Answer (score 1):

Not as much of an efficient solution, but in a comment I saw you wanted a one-liner solution.

Here I have a two-liner:

```
l1 = ['cat1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat2', 1,2,3, 'cat3',4,5,6,7,8]
l2 = ['cat1','cat2','cat3']

dct = { l2[i] : l1[l1.index(l2[i]) + 1:l1.index(l2[i+1])] for i in range(len(l2) - 1) }
dct[l2[-1]] = l1[l1.index(l2[-1]):]

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat3': ['cat3', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Basically, this code goes through every element in `l2`, initializes it as a key of `dct`, and then finds the sublist of `l1` between every key and makes that the corresponding list.

I hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any further questions/clarifications :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done most efficiently with a `while` and RegEx loop. I am assuming the key would be the same pattern.

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

#l1 is your list
pat = r"pattern_string"
i = 0
output = defaultdict(list)

while i < len(l1):
    if re.match(pat,l1[i]):
        key = l1[i]
        i += 1
    while not re.match(pat, l1[i]) and i < len(l1):
        output[key].append(l1[i])
        i += 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution here, look at @Rahul K P

Comment: Yeah, The answer was posted while i was typing. The other answer is better.

Comment: No problem, this is a good alternative that can be used by anyone if needed

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` gives us an elegant way to parse the list into the keys and the subsequent values into chunks, which we can then iterate over to create the desired result:

```
from itertools import groupby
def make_dict(data, key_names):
    result = {}
    for is_key, elements in groupby(data, lambda d: d in key_names):
        if is_key:
            for key in elements:
                result[key] = []
        else:
            result[key] = list(elements)
    return result
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> make_dict(['cat1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat2', 1, 2, 3, 'cat3', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
...           ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
{'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cat2': [1, 2, 3], 'cat3': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
>>> make_dict(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': []}
>>> make_dict(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': ['d']}
>>> make_dict(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd'])
{'a': ['b'], 'c': [], 'd': []}
>>> make_dict(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'])
{'a': [], 'b': ['c', 'd']}
```

Each of the `elements` chunks created by `groupby` is either a sequence of keys or a sequence of values (`is_key` becomes the result from the `lambda`, so that tells us which kind of chunk we have). Iterating with `l1_dic[key] = []` covers the case where there are consecutive keys in the data - since there are no intervening values, the keys in that group except for the last must have an empty list of values. When a group of values is found, it is assigned to the *most recent* key - exploiting the fact that `for` loops don't create a scope for the iteration variable.

Comment: I'm not sure this really adds anything over the simplest explicit-loop versions, but I like showing more examples of `itertools.groupby`. Note that the way it returns values is rather complex - `groupby` creates a lazy iterator of `key, group` pairs, and each group is *also* a lazy iterator over the original data. It's generally easier to iterate with these explicitly.

Comment: Hard to read compared to the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74002648/14535088